# How big are the lockers at the Leuven train station?

Tags: belgium, luggage-storage, train-stations, leuven

I'm planning on visiting Leuven next year but i'm going to need a place to store my luggage for a couple of days as i want to attend the rock werchter festival.

The festival offers lockers but they seem to be pretty small so i wanted to know if the lockers offered at the Leuven train station are big enough to fit your average travelling bag.

Comment: Average travelling bag isn't very descriptive. For some people, like myself, the average bag is a small rolling suitcase that fits in an airline overhead bin; for others it's a large hard sided suitcase that must be checked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [this page](https://rail.cc/en/leuven/leuven-railway-station/l2393), in particular the following photo:

[image: Leuven Railway Station Lockers]

Does the photo tell you enough about the locker size (around one-third the height of a door)?

If not, or if you would like a more reliable source, I suggest [contacting Belgian Rail directly](http://www.belgianrail.be/en/customer-service/contact.aspx).

Comment: But remember that you are not the only one who will want to leave luggage and what are plenty lockers in normal use will be very few during the festival.